# Accessing object key inside _.map

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

My data is structured like this currently

```
data = {
  a2321sdrf: {
    title: 'x',
    content: 'asad'
  },
  asdasd23: {
    title: 'x',
    content: 'asad'
  },
  dfxdsfds: {
    title: 'x',
    content: 'asad'
  }
}
```

Then I'm using lodash map to iterate through to output jsx. But, I can't figure out how to access the object key, to use as a key prop.

```
renderMenu() {
  return _.map(this.props.data, item => {
    return (
      <h1 key={:?}>{item.title}</h1>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key will be the second value to the iteritee function:

```
return _.map(this.props.data,
     (item, key) => { return ( <h1 key={key}>{item.title}</h1> );
```